# How to implement vertical scroll with ListView & GridView as its direct children?

Tags: flutter, dart

1. How to scroll the Container as a single Widget (as shown in the shapshot).
2. Tried SigleChildSrcollView & CustomScrollView, but the screen turns blank!

[image]

3. Error with SingleChildScrollView
   [image]

Comment: Are you getting any errors ?

Comment: When I use SingleChildScrollView, there is a white blank screen and console shows 'Scaffold' is the error-causing widget.

Comment: Can you paste the error ? It will be lot more easier.

Comment: Added the screenshot

Answer (score 1):

Try wrapping `SingleChildScrollView` in `Container` or `Expanded`.